# Поймать exception webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

Как поймать *exception* о том, что элемент не найден в *WebDriver Selenium*?

Вызов функции:

```
public void analyseScreenshot() throws IOException 
{
    boolean theEnd = true;
    while (theEnd)
    {
        if  (priceButton())
        {
            /*нажимаем на кнопки*/
        }
        else theEnd = false;
    }

}
```

Отлов *Exception*:

```
public boolean priceButton()
{
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id(ApplicationElementIDs.price));
        return true;
        }
    catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) 
        {
        return false;
        }

}
```

Суть в том, что нажимаем на кнопки, но потом они заканчиваются и нужно отловить тот момент, что найти элемент не можем, и что нужно выйти из цикла.

И, судя по всему, он зависает на строке

```
driver.findElement(By.id(ApplicationElementIDs.price))
```

и мне возвращается ошибка, что такой элемент не найден.

Comment: А попробуй написать где return false следующее e.printStackTrace() и ты увидешь, какая ошибка возникает. А так, код вполне валидный

Comment: Он не заходит в ветку catch, и я даже не могу увидеть ошибку.

Comment: try {
            driver.findElement(By.id(ApplicationElementIDs.price));
            return true;
            }
        catch (Exception e) 
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
            
            }
Попробуй так, узнаешь ошибку

Comment: Все равно не выводит ошибку, все ещё выводит сообщение, что не находит элемента.

Comment: try {
        driver.findElement(By.id(ApplicationElementIDs.price));
        return true;
        }
    catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) 
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
 return false;

Попробуй так

Comment: Попробовал сделать как вот тут: [ссылка](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2012/07/iselementpresent.html) ,с таймаутами, начало выходить в блок catch. Так что проблема можно сказать решена. Спасибо Andrew Bystrov за помощь)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы порекомендовал решить вашу проблему иначе.
Поиск списка элементов, если элементы есть кликать. Если нет, то нет)

```
List<IWebElemets> button=  driver.findElements(By.id(ApplicationElementIDs.price));

if (button.Any()) {
    button[0].Click()
} else {
    break;
}
```